# How can I disable tree sway in CS:GO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

How can I disable tree sway in Counter Strike: Global Offensive?

I have never seen them moving before and now they appear to be moving. Some smokes and stuff I use are dependent on the trees not moving.

Here are the settings that I thought would make them not move. What other settings am I missing?

- `cl_tree_sway_dir "0"`
- `cl_winddir "0"`
- `cl_windspeed "0"`

Comment: Just curious, what's stuff is dependent on trees moving?

Comment: @memescientist: That question is difficult to understand.

Answer (score 2):

You have to turn down shader detail in your video settings to medium or low

Comment: I am certain that i have all of my settings as low as they will go. I will make sure shader is low and check again. Thanks